# Split Windows on Textmate

Tags: macos, textmate

Textmate has been around for a while, I bought it in 2006. Is it possible to split windows horizontally and or vertically on Textmate nowadays? Probably someone out there made a kind of Plugin for this :-/ Like `C-x 2` when I'm on GNU Emacs to split horizontally or `C-x 3` to split vertically and have flexible control on each windows' width or `:split` on ViM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing I could find is [seandunn/window-buddy.tmbundle - GitHub](https://github.com/seandunn/window-buddy.tmbundle):

> Window Buddy is a bundle to add basic window management to TextMate
>
> Sorry but... WORK IN PROGRESS!
>
> Currently it's a bit rough and incomplete but the aim is to provide pseudo split window editing by using auxiliary windows in TextMate.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know this feature is still not possible. Mind you many people have discussed this and it is a very south-out feature http://wiki.macromates.com/Suggestions/GUI.

Comment: Any change in the last 5 years? :)

Comment: @RomanGaufman I'm wondering the same thing in 2022 :)

Comment: I have switched to VS Code and couldn't be happier, it's a fantastic editor - a bit ram hungry though.

Answer (score 1):

You can open a file in two windows at once. Whatever edits you do in one window are performed in the other as well. It's not quite the same as a single split-view window, but it's not all that different either.